# >forrtl: severe <170> program exception - stack overflow

Tags: fortran, intel

Один и тот же Intel fortran, под Linux проходит без ошибки, под windows 8 останавливается с ошибкой

> forrtl: severe <170> program exception - stack overflow

Comment: Слишком мало инфы, воспользуйтесь флагами /traceback /check:all что бы получить больше информации.

Answer (score 1):

Как видно из ошибки, у вас переполнение стека. Честно признаюсь, я ничего не понимаю в этом языке, но судя по всему дело в том, что по win и nix может различаться размер стека. На *nix его можно увеличить с помощью: `ulimit -s [newsize]`,  например можно сделать `ulimit -s unlimited`. Для windows это делается как то по другому. Steve Lionel из интелловского сапорта говорит, что под виндой это решается так:

> It's the "Stack Reserve Size" you want to set under Linker > System.
>   Or consider setting Fortran > Optimization Heap Arrays to 0. This will
>   free you from worrying about the stack in most cases.